# What is 'journal rank'? How can I get this?

Tags: journals, cv, job

I am applying for a job and the HR is asking me to update my CV with a list of publication to include authorship role, journal rank and impact factor.

I am not sure what journal rank means in here. Is there a site to go with a complete list of journal rank?

Thanks

Comment: Any journal ranking is a low quality ranking.  They are likely thinking of https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php.